# "Of" to explain possession

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-meaning, prepositional-phrases

Cambridge Dictionary says "of" can be used to explain made or consisting of; having:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/of

One of the examples quoted is "**a woman of great charm**"

The same way, can I say, "**a woman of exotic jewels**"" to explain the woman is wearing exotic jewelry?

Answer (score 9):

The structure *[ "a" + person + "of" + X ]* in this context means that X is *part of the identity* of the person. So it means more than the person merely possesses X or has X right now.

So no, "a woman of exotic jewels", does not mean she's wearing exotic jewels, but that exotic jewels are part of her identity. This could mean that she's an expert in exotic jewels, does business in them, is an avid collector, or something along those lines.

Comment: While I agree in this particular case, I think this "rule" oversimplifies. I point to the expression "A man of great wealth". This means that the man possesses the wealth, it is not an intrinsic part of him as "charm" might be. Yet this is a common phrase, perhaps even a fixed phrase. This answer does not currently account for the difference in uszge between "of jewels" and 'of wealth".

Comment: No, @DavidSiegel, _of great wealth_ is not an intrinsic part of him, but it is (presented as) part of his identity, as gotube said.

Comment: So when the thing is part of the noun's identity or like @DavidSiegel said it is a defining characteristic of the noun, this structure works. Say for instance, if the woman is used to wearing exotic jewels, if the woman can be identified as someone who usually wears exotic jewels, I should be good to say "a woman of exotic jewels" Am I right?

Comment: @Ammu I would say so, yes. See the sentence that includes that phrase in my answer.

Comment: @ColinFine, not really, if someone possesses great wealth you can say that they are a person of great wealth regardless of their identity.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: you are using "identity" in its primary meaning. I was using it in sense 2 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/identity#Noun).

Answer (score 3):

In the structure "A {noun} of {noun phrase}"  the noun phrase (NP) is normally a defining or identifying characteristic of the noun. It will often be a permanent or enduring characteristic of the noun, or where it is not permanent will either be perceived as at least somewhat enduring, or else serves to distinguish the noun form other similar instances of the same kind of thing. This constructionist is not typically used for merely descriptive NPs that are inherently temporary.

Let us look at the other examples given in the same group by the Cambridge Dictionary. They are:

> - dresses of lace and silk
> - plates of gold and silver
> - [a] land of ice and snow
> - [a] subject of very little interest

Note that in the first two, the NP after "Of" states the materiel of which the initial noun is constructed,  In the third it states what seems to be a characteristic that is both enduring, and is being used to define the initial noun.

In the suggested example:

> a woman of exotic jewels

is meant to indicate merely that the woman is wearing such jewels, this is not an enduring characteristic of hers, and so this construction would be misleading and sound odd to a native speaker. With additional context, it might be used to define the woman. For example:

> She was a women of exotic jewels; she was never seen without at least five or six unusual stones set in intricate and unique mountings.

Given that context, the "exotic jewels" have become the ***defining*** characteristic of the woman, and the construction is proper.

Let us consider some other typical uses of this construction. Some examples:

> - Mr Jones is a man of great wealth.
> - This is a wine of distinction.
> - I heard a scream of terror.
> - John is a student of promise.
> - The ship was rocked by a wave of great size.

While the wealth is presumably not an inherent feature of Mr. Jones, it is somewhat enduring, and is being used to distinguish him from other people. The wine is being defined by its distinction, that is its high quality. The scream is being defined by the emotion it expresses. The wave is being distinguished from other waves by its size. Each of these seems to fall within the principle stated above that, the "X of Y" construction is used for defining or inherent characteristics, and not otherwise.

An interesting example forms the second sentence of the well-known story "The Open Window" by Saki (H. H. Munro). The sentence is:

> Framton Nuttel endeavoured to say the correct something which should duly flatter the niece of the moment without unduly discounting the aunt that was to come.

The "niece of the moment" is the young woman to whom Nuttel  was then speaking. More generally "The X of the moment" is the thing currently under discussion, ore receiving  attention, with the implication that this may soon change., But it serves to define **which** X is meant.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to your intended question -'of'( or genitive marker's' which is attached to the possessor NP, here 'woman') is used to indicate possessor so in your question 'a woman of great charm' means a woman who possesses great charm but I  think your pharse ' a woman of exotic jewels'is semantically unacceptable. To indicate that the woman possesses or wears  the jewels rather you should say ' a woman with exotic jewels'(ie 'a woman wearing exotic jewels' ).

Comment: So "of" does or does not indicate possession? What makes it semantically unacceptable in this case?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t mean to detract from the other answers,
but few things in English mean only one thing,
or can be used only one way. 
A couple of semi-random observations:

1. “[a] N<sub>1</sub> of N<sub>2</sub>” can mean
   that N<sub>1</sub> *belongs **to*** N<sub>2</sub>,
   i.e., that N<sub>2</sub> *has* N<sub>1</sub>, in some sense. 
   (This is somewhat the opposite of your “jewels” example
   and the “great wealth” example.)

   - “Excalibur is the sword of my great-grandfather.” 
     means that it is my great-grandfather’s sword;
     i.e., that it belonged to my great-grandfather.
   - “Bart is the brother of Lisa and Maggie.” 
     means that Bart is Lisa and Maggie’s brother;
     i.e., that Lisa and Maggie *have* a brother, and he is Bart.
   - “Light is the opposite of darkness.” 
     means that light is darkness’s opposite.
   - “Superman is a defender of the downtrodden.” 
     means that Superman is the downtrodden’s defender.
2. The “[a] N<sub>1</sub> of N<sub>2</sub>” construct
   can refer to a temporary or transitory relationship,
   rather than a defining or identifying characteristic. 
   Borrowing (and changing) an example from [David Siegel’s answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/329353/357),

     John is a student of economics.

   could be a broad, timeless description of John’s interests. 
   Or it could be a statement about his (current) registered major
   (i.e., his primary field of study) at some school,
   in which case it could change at a moment’s notice.